# Automation Error / Catastrophic Failure when debugging VSTO project

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, vsto

I'm building a document-level VSTO customization for an Excel 2016 workbook, and I'm encountering this error repeatedly in the development process.  Basically, Visual Studio 2015 builds the project, Excel loads the workbook, and *immediately* Excel displays an "Automation Error / Catastrophic Failure" message.  It kicks me into the VBA editor, but there's no code on the screen to edit.

I read in a few places that the error means there is something wrong with the "References" settings in the VBE, but it won't let me open that screen, the option is grayed out.  Anything else I try to do just pulls that error up again.  The only way out is to stop the process through Visual Studio.  If I open the source workbook directly from the project folder, the same problem occurs, and I have to quit Excel via Task Manager.

This problem has been coming and going over the past 24 hours; last night and this morning it wasn't happening for some reason, so I was having no issues running and testing my project, but now the problem is back.  If anyone has an idea of what could be causing this problem (bearing in mind it must be something that has not been constant over the past day), I'm all ears.  Even just an idea of what to look for would be helpful, as I don't even know what this error means or what kinds of things to look for.  This is my first VSTO project and I've been pretty excited by what I was able to accomplish when this error wasn't coming up every time, so I'd like to eliminate the problem permanently.

Edit:  I should point out that the reason I included VSTO in the question title is that this workbook was totally fine before I started the VSTO project.  But I saw this error when I tried to run the VSTO project for the first time, yesterday.

Comment: Please see how to provide a [mcve] - if you can't then your question is probably too broad for this site.

Comment: So, the workbook was used as the basis for the VSTO project? It contains VBA code? And what does that VBA code do? Things executing when the workbook is opened?

Comment: I think I figured it out myself, but I'll still comment in case someone else ends up here with the same problem.  Yes, the workbook was the basis for the VSTO project.  Yes, it contained existing VBA code.  Some of that code was user-defined functions, which apparently were trying to execute when the workbook opened so long as automatic calculations were enabled.  Those UDFs call on VB.net code, which apparently had issues but the VS debugger couldn't get to them until I stopped the function from auto-executing on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I "kinda-sorta" figured out my own problem.  I'm still not 100% sure what caused it in the first place, but I'll leave this here for anyone else who runs into the same issue someday:

When you get this error, don't despair like I did because the VBE window has no code highlighted as the problem area.  Look through ALL the VBA code in every object/module/sheet; in my case, I eventually found a function highlighted as the cause of the problem.  I was able to bypass the error temporarily by turning off automatic calculations, and I commented out the offending function.  It broke some things in my workbook to do so, but it gave me the opportunity to debug my VB.net code in Visual Studio, and when I uncommented the "problem" VBA function after doing so, it all worked perfectly fine.